# zf2 making each module personal navigation and add style

Tags: css, navigation, zend-framework2

[zf2 way to set up a navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551736/zf2-way-to-set-up-a-navigation-bar)
there is a sample to do navigation for all site
but how can i do this for each module personal and add css for it?

Comment: or can someone give me links for good zf2 tutorials? not only User Guide on http://framework.zend.com

Comment: i fine some solution for adding specific menu at my module but how i can manage the css syle for it? <ul class="navigation"> ??

Comment: the solution was in the config 

    'dashbord' => array(
                    'label' => 'Dashbord',
                    'route' => 'nav',
                  'class' => 'nav-bar',),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was in the partial navigation!